# How to do a two-sample z-test with <3 observations?

Tags: r

The accepted way to do z-tests in R seems to be the `z.test` function from `BSDA` package.  However, it doesn't seem to work with less than 3 observations.  This is confusing to me, because the z-test shouldn't require more than one observation.  It shouldn't use the sample to estimate the variance - it should use the inputted sigma.

Am I doing something wrong?  Is there a better way to do z-tests in R?

Here you can see the z-test succeed with 3 observations in each group and fail with 1.

```r
library(BSDA)
  
s <- 0.2
x <- c(1, 1.5, 1)
y <- c(2, 2.5, 2)

z.test(x, y, sigma.x = s, sigma.y = s)
#> 
#>  Two-sample z-Test
#> 
#> data:  x and y
#> z = -6.1237, p-value = 9.141e-10
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -1.3200608 -0.6799392
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of x mean of y 
#>  1.166667  2.166667

x <- 1
y <- 2

z.test(x, y, sigma.x = s, sigma.y = s)
#> Error in z.test(x, y, sigma.x = s, sigma.y = s): not enough x observations
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The test I am working with has documented precision, so I have a reliable specification of the variance.  Correct me if I'm wrong - I think this enables z-tests with single observations.

Comment: I see. Looking more at the function and its operations internally, I am also not clear why the author explicitly fails on lengths of 2 or less. Since it's using externally-sourced variance (`sigma.x` and `sigma.y`), that suggests individual values for the test itself (assuming population sizes of 2 or more each) should be okay. Perhaps a bug report to the author?

Comment: You seem to be looking for the summarized z-test, knowing variance does not mean anything without knowing the mean and sample size. https://rdrr.io/cran/BSDA/man/zsum.test.html

Comment: I do know the means and sample sizes.  In the second example, the means are 1, 2 and the sample sizes 1, 1.

Comment: `zsum.test(1, .2, 1, 1, .2, 1)` throws the same error.  It doesn't like `n.x = 1` or`n.y = 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the commenters that there doesn't seem to be any good reason that `BSDA::z.test` can't handle a two-sample Z test with an n (per group) of 1.

I looked around with `library(sos); findFn("z test")` and found `misty::test.z`, but that also seems to have issues.

However, the `PASWR` package (which has the same maintainer as `BSDA` !) appears to work OK:

```r
PASWR::z.test(x, y, sigma.x = s, sigma.y = s)

    Two Sample z-test

data:  x and y
z = -3.5355, p-value = 0.000407
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -1.5543615 -0.4456385
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
        1         2
```

The p-value agrees with the direct calculation:

```r
2*pnorm(abs(x-y)/sqrt(s^2+s^2), lower.tail = FALSE)
```